# Which are the kind of applications/services/components where the Actors model (Scala, Erlang) is best suited for?

Tags: scala, erlang, actor

Besides the benefits of this model over the shared-memory model, I'm just trying to understand where to apply it for higher levels use-cases.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka

Answer (score 1):

As to Scala, Actors model fits most of the multi-threaded cases one can think about:

- Swing GUI application
- Web Applications (see [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) framework)
- Application Server in multicore environment:

  - Batch processing of requests/data
  - Background tracking tasks
  - Notifications & Scheduled tasks

Actors model makes design much clearer and greatly simplifies interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

- OTP Framework : Provides really good framework for network based applications.
- Helps in making fault tolerant applications . (process restart using Supervisor's in OTP).
- Both Synchronous and Asynchronous modes of communication can be done using **gen_server**.
- Event based callbacks can be used using **gen_event**.
- State machine can be programmed easily using **gen_fsm** (In case you need to follow some states in your application).
- A process crash does not bring the whole application down. Only that particular process crashes.
- Functional programming language.
- A lot easier to program at binary level.
- Garbage collection.
- Native compilation option.
- Fair amount of good useful modules are available.
- Able to make good solid concurrent applications easily.

And lots more.... I really enjoyed working on some applications in erlang , making those in c/c++ would have been very difficult.