# What are some common use cases for using the Akka Microkernel?

Tags: java, scala, akka

Based on the docs on akki.io I'm not seeing what common use cases the MicroKernel solves? Does anyone have some simple real world use cases?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka

Comment: @KenWhite: The question is not about Akka, but about Akka Microkernel...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Akka Microkernel module gives you a very light-weight and free "application server" bundle so it's easy to distribute and run your Akka application.

Read more about it here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/modules/microkernel.html

Comment: Is the microkernel something you would distribute with your application? Or would you distribute your application and expect someone to download the microkernel separately and use it to load/execute the application? I assume it is the latter since Akka does the former without the microkernel.  Can it execute multiple applications at once?

Comment: Either you distribute your app inside a microkernel, or you expect others to already have a microkernel set up.

Comment: that answers it perfectly, so instead of running my app as a tomcat webapp, I could just deploy it without tomcat using the microkernel to load it up(no longer as a webapp obviously)