# When will Akka bring better performance?

Tags: performance, scala, akka

I just wrote a JDBC connection pool using Akka.

It uses an actor to hold a "maxPoolSize" collection of real database connections. The caller asks the pool actor for a connection and receives a `Future[Connection]` and the connection's status becomes 'busy' until the caller returns it to the pool on `connection.close`. If all the connections are busy, the new incoming request for connection will be placed on a waiting queue (also held by the pool actor). Later when a connection is returned, the waiting request will be fulfilled.

The implementation of this logic is very easy in akka, just dozens of lines of code. However when using the BoneCP [Multithread Test](http://jolbox.com/dynamic-benchmark.html) to test the performance (i.e. the caller `close` the connection immediately when the `Future[Connection]` returned by `getConnection` is fulfilled. The benchmark `traversed` all the `close` request and `Await` for the result `Future`), I found that the Akka version is slower than many other connection pool implementations such as tomcat-jdbc, BoneCP or even commons DBCP.

What I have tried for tuning:

1. splitting the pool actor into multiple ones each hold part of all the real connections
2. tweaking some of the default-dispatcher config parameters (throughput, parallelism)

but saw no noticable improvement.

My question is :

1. Is this a suitable use case that using akka will get better performance?
2. If it is, how can I get similar or better benchmark data than those handcrafted-threading connection pool implementations?
3. If it is not, why? Are there any established criteria that can help me decide **when to use akka**?

Comment: I'm not terribly surprised. Not to doubt your development skills in the slightest, but these other libs have quite a bit more development time put into them to solve this very specific problem

Comment: would love to see answers to #3 point!

Comment: I think #3 is covered well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka

Comment: how does the benchmark behave when all the connections are gone? is the driver locking?

Comment: I would search for some blocking behavior in your code. If it's just dozens of lines, maybe you can paste it here?

Answer (score 3):

To answer question #1, this is not a use case where Akka will excel in speed. You have basically taken a problem that is usually solved with a concurrent data-structure optimized for multiple readers and writers and serialized it through a single actor.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create [Router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html), which will spawn several slave Actors, each representing a single connection.

But be aware that there could be potential race conditions.

Also, what version of Scala and Akka you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Akka might be a good choice for highly parallel computations while a JDBC connection pool is not a good example for highly parallel computations.

Comment: elcome to stackoverflow!This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer.