# Scala integration with Rabbit MQ

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, actor

I have a back-end Scala application that needs to integrate with RabbitMQ.  The back-end Scala app executes long running tasks asynchronously.  Messages to execute the tasks are queued into  RabbitMQ by a web client.  The back-end application then consumes each of these messages, executing the corresponding long-running tasks.

Should Scala app directly consume the message from RabbitMQ and simply have the corresponding tasks be processed using Futures?   Or is it better to use Akka Actors to receive these messages from RabbitMQ, and then execute the long-running tasks?

What are the pro's and con's of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

`Future`s sound like a simpler approach for your use case combined with the RabbitMQ Java client.

My model for choosing actors v. futures is: prefer futures, switching to actors when I feel I have a good use case for them (see [Good use case for Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka/4494613#4494613) for some examples). For example, if you were trying to divide-and-conquer the batch workloads (as the linked answer states), actors may serve your purposes well.

Use the RabbitMQ Java examples below as a starting point, modifying to do work in futures so that the thread polling the work queue is not blocked. I included links to both work queue and RPC examples in case you need to return some response (RabbitMQ is good at this case as it has a concept of `correlationId` built in).

Java RabbitMQ examples:

[Work Queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html)

[Remote procedure call (RPC)](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html)