# Akka and RESTful Services

Tags: web-services, rest, akka

On SO there is a heavily-upvoted (albeit "closed") question entitled ["*Good use case for Akka*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka) that I am looking for some further resolution on.

Although not the accepted answer, Akka's own Viktor Klang weighed in with a [heavily-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494613/4009451) where he states that RESTful web services are a good use case for the actor-based framework.

But this seems to be in direct conflict with the most basic staple of Akka: Akka is for asynchronous systems, whereas REST services need to be synchronous, and are typically expected to produce results within 200ms (e.g., I shouldn't have to wait 6 seconds for a simple GET to return some JSON to me).

So I ask: how is Akka ideal for REST services if it is implicitly asynchronous and non-blocking, or is this just self-marketing hype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that asynchronous means slow? :)

Of course because of the nature of HTTP protocol, from client point of view HTTP calls will be synchronous. But *internally* Akka will use its asynchronous capabilities to process requests as soon as possible.

[spray.io](http://spray.io/) is a standard Akka HTTP layer that will be replaced with Akka HTTP module soon (which is basically Spray 2.0). It's very lightweight and super fast.

And [this](https://github.com/sap1ens/akka-microservice/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sap1ens/api/Example1Routes.scala#L57) is an example about how you can integrate synchronous HTTP and asynchronous Akka Actors. As you can see it creates Future and sends result back when it's done.

More advanced examples: http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/